# How can you generalize a function so you can pass any dataset without changing the parameters?

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm interested in designing a user built function where I input any dataset containing factors and a numeric, and producing an output in csv format.

I have tried using various forms of dplyr but I think *select* extracts my variable, and I still want it part of my dataset so the function organizes my various factors.

I have come up with 2 ideas for a function. Pieces of them work but I get errors with I shove everything into the function

```
the_function <- function(df){
  library(dplyr) #Import library
  
  #Computes Summary statistics independently
  Avg <-  df %>% 
    group_by(across(where(is.factor))) %>%
    summarise(across(where(is.numeric), mean)) #Thanks to akrun
              
  Med <- df %>% 
    group_by(across(where(is.factor))) %>%
    summarise(across(where(is.numeric)), median)
    
  StDev <- df %>% 
    group_by(across(where(is.factor))) %>%
    summarise(across(where(is.numeric)), sd)
  
  #Parse objects to new dataframe and write dataframe to CSV file
  e <-  data.frame(Avg, Med, Sample, StDev)
  return(e)
}
```

I'm comparing dplyr to base R, less code for brevity

```
another_function <- function(df){
  for(x in df){
    if(is.numeric(x) == TRUE){
      x <- x
      break
    }
  }
  ag <- aggregate(x~., data = df, mean) #So it aggregates n groups. Running into issues sometimes with .groups
  e <- data.frame(ag)
  return(e)
}
```

I'm curious about why dplyr evolved and how to produce more complex functions that I can use in research and consulting in the future and I'm interested in user-built functions in general.
Thank you for your wisdom!

Comment: You need the `%>%` before the `summarise_at`

Answer (score 0):

The pipe for `dplyr` can be written as

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    group_by(across(where(is.factor))) %>%
    summarise(across(where(is.numeric), mean))
```

---

In the OP's code, the columns are repeated as we are calling multiple `across`.  Instead it can be in a single `across`

```
library(dplyr) 
the_function <- function(df){



     out <- df %>%
        group_by(across(where(is.factor))) %>%
        summarise(
          Observations = n(),

          across(where(is.numeric),  
         list(Mean = ~ mean(., na.rm = TRUE),
              Median = ~ median(., na.rm = TRUE),
              Sd.dev = ~ sd(., na.rm = TRUE))))

   return(out)
  }
```

-testing

```
the_function(iris)
# A tibble: 3 x 17
  Species    Observations Sepal.Length_Mean Sepal.Length_Median Sepal.Length_Sd.d… Sepal.Width_Mean Sepal.Width_Medi… Sepal.Width_Sd.d… Petal.Length_Me…
* <fct>             <int>             <dbl>               <dbl>              <dbl>            <dbl>             <dbl>             <dbl>            <dbl>
1 setosa               50              5.01                 5                0.352             3.43               3.4             0.379             1.46
2 versicolor           50              5.94                 5.9              0.516             2.77               2.8             0.314             4.26
3 virginica            50              6.59                 6.5              0.636             2.97               3               0.322             5.55
# … with 8 more variables: Petal.Length_Median <dbl>, Petal.Length_Sd.dev <dbl>, Petal.Width_Mean <dbl>, Petal.Width_Median <dbl>,
#   Petal.Width_Sd.dev <dbl>, Observations_Mean <dbl>, Observations_Median <int>, Observations_Sd.dev <dbl>
```

---

Regarding the `base R`, we can get similar summary output, but it is not that flexible as `tidyverse`

```
the_function_base <- function(df) {
      grp <- names(df)[sapply(df, is.factor)]
      num_cols <- names(df)[sapply(df, is.numeric)]
      fmla <- reformulate(grp, response = '.')
      f1 <- function(x) {
              c(Mean = mean(x, na.rm = TRUE),
              Median = median(x, na.rm = TRUE),
              Sd.dev = sd(x, na.rm = TRUE))
          }
      do.call(data.frame, aggregate(fmla, df[c(grp, num_cols)], FUN = 
           f1))
    }
```

-testing

```
the_function_base(iris)
     Species Sepal.Length.Mean Sepal.Length.Median Sepal.Length.Sd.dev Sepal.Width.Mean Sepal.Width.Median Sepal.Width.Sd.dev Petal.Length.Mean
1     setosa             5.006                 5.0           0.3524897            3.428                3.4          0.3790644             1.462
2 versicolor             5.936                 5.9           0.5161711            2.770                2.8          0.3137983             4.260
3  virginica             6.588                 6.5           0.6358796            2.974                3.0          0.3224966             5.552
  Petal.Length.Median Petal.Length.Sd.dev Petal.Width.Mean Petal.Width.Median Petal.Width.Sd.dev
1                1.50           0.1736640            0.246                0.2          0.1053856
2                4.35           0.4699110            1.326                1.3          0.1977527
3                5.55           0.5518947            2.026                2.0          0.2746501
```

Comment: It would seem I failed to follow my own logic to its conclusion. S revised my question and code hoping to state my problem more concisely, and because with my first post I wasn't sure how exactly to introduce this. Thank you for looking over it before.

Comment: @Ace I updated with `base R` as well.  If these help, please consider to accept solution

Answer (score 0):

I had to jump over to R Studio community for some more discourse, but I have found a solution to my program

```
the_function <- function(df){
  library(dplyr) #Import library
  
  #Computes Summary statistics
  out <- df %>%
    group_by(across(where(is.factor))) %>%
    summarise(
      Observations = n(),
      Mean = across(.cols = where(is.numeric),
                     .fns = ~ mean(.x, na.rm = T)),
      Median = across(.cols = where(is.numeric),
                      .fns = ~ median(.x, na.rm = T)),
      St.dev = across(.cols = where(is.numeric),
                      .fns = ~ sd(.x, na.rm = T)))
  return(out)
}
```

For some reason, it is producing repeated columns and columns with NA values, but I have been able to verify it with separate datasets. I assume the extra columns are coming from quirks within dplyr::summarise(), but it's past my bedtime, so I'll leave it.

Is it a fool's errand to accomplish the same task in base R? Thanks for my first jump into the world of data science.

Comment: You just need a single `across` i.e. `across(where(is.numeric),  list(Mean = ~ mean(., na.rm = TRUE), Median = ~ median(., na.rm = TRUE), Sd.dev = ~ sd(., na.rm = TRUE))))`

Comment: And minimize repetitive code. Alright, thank you for the help

Comment: if the below solution works, please consider to accept sollution. thanks